# Boolean Problem Simplification

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I am trying to simplify the boolean function F= ~A~BC + A~B~C + A~BC + AB~C + ABC and I know that correct answer is F= A + ~BC.

My attempt is:

~A~BC + A~B(~C+C) + AB(~C+C)

~A~BC+ A(~B+B)

~A~BC + A

I am not sure where to go from here. I know it's standard to mulitpy by one or add zero, but I'm not getting it work. 
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

$a\lnot b\lnot c$ and $a\lnot bc$ combine to make $a\lnot b$.
$abc$ and $ab\lnot c$ combine to make $ab$.
$a\lnot b$ and $ab$ combine to make $a$.
$\lnot a\lnot bc$ and $a\lnot bc$ combine to make $\lnot bc$.

$\begin{array}{c|cccc}
&-00&-01&-11&-10\\
\hline
0--&·&*&·&·\\
1--&*&*&*&*
\end{array}$

Comment: How did you get ab'c to combine with a'b'c if you have already factored it out ?

Comment: can you do that? @Senex Ægypti Parvi

Comment: @dwebber \ The fact that a term has been used once does not disqualify it from being used again. In the Karnaugh map for this particular set of desired results you may notice that the term for $a\lnot bc$ can be "surrounded" twice, indicating applicability in logical combinations twice.

Comment: @ Senex Ægypti Parvi thanks, I'm taking a intro to logic design at my university, and we just started the quarter, so have not learned KMapping yet. Is there a way to simplify this expression just using algebraic manipulation. Thanks

Comment: @dwebber \ Yes, by using a Quine-McClusky reduction of a logical function. This method is much more useful than the KMap, which can only be of use in problems involving up to four variables. I am sure your instructor will get around to covering this with you.

Comment: @dwebber \ I have added a rudimentary KMap to my answer. Notice that orthogonally connected cells only differ by one bit.